# Accepting / Rejecting an user

Tags: php, facebook

I have developed a code, where a user registers himself and when the registration is successful, all the details are sent to the admin. The admin gets a request about the candidate and he can accept/reject the candidate after examining his details(Similar to FB friend request). For this, I maintained a field in the DB called 'Acceptance' which is a boolean value. If it is zero, the request is not yet processed and if it is one, the admin accepted the request. I am using just a bit for this and I don't know how far this is secure and correct. I am coding in PHP and I am new to this field. Is there any better way to implement the same? Please help me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This is a good approach. What I usually do is to keep more states.
For example zero is the initial value when user registers, and then 1 if the admin accepts the user and 2 if the admin rejects the user. this is a good approach if you want to give the admin a screen with a list of those who need to be approved excluding those who are already been rejected.

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement Boolean variable doesn't work as it has only two options '0' or '1' .

You mentioned that '0' set for application not processed, '1' for accepted. But how will you update if its rejected ??

You better take integer field instead Boolean, update this field with '0'  or '1' or '2'.

And write logic based on these options. If its '0'   not processed, '1' as accepted and '2' as rejected.

Comment: When the admin rejects the candidate, the details of the candidate are deleted from the DB.